# Why the 'to be' verb is used in these sentences?

Tags: verbs, gerunds, bare-infinitives

> 1) 'got to be' instead of 'are'
>
> You ***got to be*** kidding me
>
> **INSTEAD OF**
>
> You ***are*** kidding me

.

> 2) 'bare to be + gerund' instead of 'bare infinitive'
>
> We can't ***be cutting*** corners anymore
>
> **INSTEAD OF**
>
> We can't ***cut*** corners anymore

Question:

> Why the 'to be' verb is used in these sentences?

Answer (score 2):

> You'**ve** got to be kidding me

is more the hypothetical question of whether or not you're kidding me, "*got to be*" is an emphasizer, whereas

> You **are** kidding me.

is a certain statement whereas the hypothetical equivalent would be

> You **are** kidding me, *aren't you*?
>   **Are** you kidding me?

In your second sentences

> We can't **cut** corners anymore

is a statement of fact, a change in policy and practice, whereas

> We can't **be cutting** corners anymore

has more the feeling that cutting corners can not be considered a thing to do anymore